# How can I configure a webservice in .NET 4 without using app.config

Tags: wcf, deployment, app-config

I have a .NET 4 project made of a EXE project and a class library. The class library contains a reference to a webservice (using WCF).
Everything works ok only if I have deployed the app.config file (that contains the info about the binding) along with my exe. How can I have everything configured by code without the need to deploy an app.config file (I don't want my users to change those settings).
Thank you.
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ChannelFactory class to generate proxies to your services.
Everything you configure through the configuration file can also be done using code.

You just need to instantiate an instance of the correct binding and configure its properties according to the service requirements on the other side.

For example:

```
private IDisposableService GetClient()
{
    var netBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    netBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
    netBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;

    var factory = new ChannelFactory<IDisposableService>(netBinding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri(ServerUrl)));
    factory.Credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
    factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

    var channel = factory.CreateChannel();

    return channel;
}

interface IDisposableService : IYourService, IDisposable
{
}
```

Then you can simply use:

```
using (var proxy = GetClient())
{
    // call proxy here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
MyServiceResponseClient embEvalServiceClient = new MyServiceResponseClient (new BasicHttpBinding(),
                                                    new EndpointAddress(new Uri(url)));

if (embEvalServiceClient != null)
{
    embEvalServiceClient.GetPendingEvalsCompleted += getPendingEvalsCompletedHandler;
    embEvalServiceClient.GetPendingEvalsAsync(attemptId);
}
```